Why ionic compounds don't usually crystalize in zinc blende structure?
Why ionic compounds (I mean the character of bonding) don't usually crystallize in zinc blende structure, but covalent ones do, even if it is not expected from the radius of atoms?
For instance AgI and CuCl crystallize in zinc blende structure even though the radius ratio does not indicate it.
